# Error: Cannot find module '@vue/babel-preset-app'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli-3

When I create a new vue application, and I run the server I get an error, after the compilation failed.
Does anyone have where the problem comes from?

Here is a screen shot of my Terminal and my browser.
[image: Terminal vue.js error]

The main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

And the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vuedemo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solve this issue, after run this command. 
`npm install @vue/babel-preset-app --save-dev`

then it throw me this error 
`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)`

I launched the following command
`npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack`

it gave me a new error
`Failed to resolve loader: vue-style-loader`

after that I run a `npm install vue-style-loader`

and it gave me another error angain, this one `Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'`
Finally I run the next following command, `npm i autoprefixer` and It worked for me.

Comment: I got away with just `npm install @vue/babel-preset-app -dev`

Answer (score 5):

Adding `@vue/babel-preset-app` as one of the `devDependencies` should solve the issue.

If you are using npm, do

```
npm install @vue/babel-preset-app --save-dev
```

for yarn

```
yarn add @vue/babel-preset-app --save-dev
```

for pnpm

```
pnpm install @vue/babel-preset-app --save-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have already tried this solution and the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you run that at the same place that throws this error? Or does it now throws a different error?

Comment: yes I run it the same place, and it render a new error.

Comment: Here is the error ```Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same initial problem. For me, this was all fixed with a `yarn upgrade`.